# Is there a way for my .NET Blazor WASM application to not get blocked by most firewalls?

Tags: dll, firewall, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

A few months ago my team and I redeveloped out .NET MVC Software with **Blazor WASM**. Since we released out first version with Blazor, many of our existing (and new) **customers are not able to load our page**, because the **.dll-files are blocked** by most corporate **firewalls**.

Mostly this gets solved by the customers themselves, because they just tell their IT-staff to **unblock files from our IP.**

The problem is, we want to serve a customer who has several (hundreds) of branches and many of them have their own IT-defense-system. We can't wait for hundreds of companies to unblock our application.

**So, is there anything we can do against this problem?**

How do other webassembly-applications tackle this problems? I can't imagine that applications like
[figma](https://www.figma.com/login) are not working for so many companies...

Many people and even microsoft suggest, to just change the file-ending of .dll-files to .bin and this seems to work for a few people. We unfortunately had not a single customer where this was the solution.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5477#issuecomment-599148931

This is the solution from microsoft, that has unfortunately not worked..

Comment: Most other webassembly-applications don't use dll-files so that seems to be only an blazor specific problem. And to be honest why use DLL at all when WASM is mostly the same thing whith other bytecode.